# Share iPhone Tethering Through Airport Express?

Tags: iphone, airport, tethering

Is it possible to tether my iPhone in some way to my Airport Express (latest generation) so that my tethered connection is served to all my computers connected to my Airport Express?

I can easily connect each of my computers wirelessly to my iPhone, however, doing so means I loose that local network. If it can't be done with an Airport Express, can it be done any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it's not the best way but you can tether your connection to one computer, and the share the Internet connection through Ethernet other the network (Airport Express Ethernet input) from that computer.

If you have a Mac it's simple. Go to `Settings`, then `Sharing` and finally flag `Internet sharing`. You have to configure it for sharing the Internet connection from Wi-Fi to Ethernet.